# Rows with duplicate column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am pretty sure there are rows with duplicate column values in the table:

```
SELECT
    TenancyReferralKey,
    FromDate,
    ToDate,
    ToDate_Value,
    ReferralID,
    ReferralFor,
    ReferralStatus
FROM dm.Dim_TenancyReferral
WHERE ReferralID IN ('1138', '1940', '1946')
ORDER BY ReferralID
```

[image]

And I am trying to count the number of rows with the duplicated `ReferralID`:

```
SELECT
    TenancyReferralKey,
    FromDate,
    ToDate,
    ToDate_Value,
    ReferralID,
    ReferralFor,
    ReferralStatus,
    COUNT(*) [Occurrences]
FROM dm.Dim_TenancyReferral
GROUP BY
    TenancyReferralKey,
    FromDate,
    ToDate,
    ToDate_Value,
    ReferralID,
    ReferralFor,
    ReferralStatus
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

[image]

But getting empty result set.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are grouping by a number of non-unique columns (`TenancyReferralKey`, `FromDate`, `ToDate`, `ToDate_Value`). If you remove those you will receive the duplicates you are after e.g.

```
SELECT
    ReferralID,
    ReferralFor,
    ReferralStatus,
    COUNT(*) [Occurrences]
FROM dm.Dim_TenancyReferral
GROUP BY
    ReferralID,
    ReferralFor,
    ReferralStatus
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit the `COUNT` statement in your query. `COUNT(*) [Occurrences]` counts the number of rows in the table when grouped by all of the columns in the `GROUP BY` statement. So every row has its own set of values (there are no cases where the *entire record* is a duplicate). Try

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT
    TenancyReferralKey,
    FromDate,
    ToDate,
    ToDate_Value,
    ReferralID,
    ReferralFor,
    ReferralStatus,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ReferralID) AS Occurences
FROM dm.Dim_TenancyReferral
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    cte
WHERE
   Occurences > 0
;
```

Comment: Thanks for that elaboration and showing CTE. I will look at the `OVER` and `PARTITION BY` keywords.